How to disable InteractivePopGestureRecognizer for specific page in .net maui for iOS?
On first loading page when I SwipeLeft on iOS the app gets crashed. To fix this I have created CustomShellRenderer
public class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    protected override IShellSectionRenderer CreateShellSectionRenderer(ShellSection shellSection)
    {
        return new CustomSectionRenderer(this);
    }
}

public class CustomSectionRenderer : ShellSectionRenderer
{
    public CustomSectionRenderer(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = false;
    }
}

This fixes the crash and disables the Swipe navigation for entire app in iOS. I want to do this just for Specific page. How to do it?

The question should be "Why does the app crash?", and not how to disable the default behavior. What exactly is the issue here?

We do not get any event called when in .net maui for that iOS swipe back. Can we? that's why I'm not able to identify the reason of crash. But looks like its because navigation stack is empty and its try to go back on swipe that's what making app crash.

If you suspect a bug, have you considered checking in the GitHub repo for existing issues?

Yes I have got the work around from the one, but its not the same one: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16471

In ViewDidLoad(), have you tried to add if (Shell.Current.CurrentPage.GetType().Name.Equals("SpecificPageName")){  InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = false; }?

Yes, I did tried that. Its not working.

@Divyesh Thanks for your response, I see you commented the thread:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16471#issuecomment-2107459544, you can follow up there.
